# Which derivative to use in the change of metric tensor due to a gauge transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, gauge-theory, differentiation

I'm used to calculating the change in the metric due to a gauge transformation in the following way:

The gauge transformation up to linear order is

\begin{equation}
x^\mu \rightarrow x' ^\mu =x^\mu + \xi^\mu
\end{equation}

If I think of the metric as a tensor, then the following identity holds

\begin{equation}
g'_{\mu\nu}(x')=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu}g_{\alpha\beta}(x)
\end{equation}

To linear order the coordinate change is just $\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}=\delta^\alpha_\mu-\xi^\alpha_{\ \ \ ,\mu}$ so we get the usual

\begin{equation}
g'_{\mu\nu}(x')=g_{\mu\nu}(x)-\xi_{\mu,\nu}-\xi_{\nu,\mu}
\end{equation}

Eq. 7.13 on Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry claims that the metric is corrected by $-\xi_{\mu;\nu}-\xi_{\nu;\mu}$ where the $;$ indicates a covariant derivative instead of a flat one. Since he is calculating this in the context of linearized gravity he throws the covariant derivative and ends up with the same result as I have. However, I was wondering if there's a way to get the covariant derivative with the tensorial method I'm using here. He uses a more complicated derivation involving pullbacks and Lie derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost the right formula, you just didn't follow through a bit more. We start with
$$
g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = g_{\mu\nu}(x) - g_{\alpha\mu}(x) \partial_\nu \xi^\alpha(x)- g_{\alpha\nu}(x) \partial_\mu \xi^\alpha(x) 
$$
Note that $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ depends on $x$ so you cannot move it into the derivative, i.e. $g_{\alpha\mu}(x) \partial_\nu \xi^\alpha(x) \neq \partial_\nu \xi_\mu(x)$.

Next, we write
$$
g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = g'_{\mu\nu}(x+\xi) = g'_{\mu\nu}(x) + \xi^\alpha \partial_\alpha g'_{\mu\nu}(x) + O(\xi^2).
$$
However, we also have $g' = g + O(\xi)$. Thus,
$$
g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = g'_{\mu\nu}(x+\xi) = g'_{\mu\nu}(x) + \xi^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}(x) + O(\xi^2).
$$
Plugging all this in, we find
$$
g'_{\mu\nu}(x) - g_{\mu\nu}(x) = - g_{\alpha\mu}(x) \partial_\nu \xi^\alpha(x)- g_{\alpha\nu}(x) \partial_\mu \xi^\alpha(x) -  \xi^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}(x).
$$
The final step for you is to prove is that
$$
 g_{\alpha\mu}(x) \partial_\nu \xi^\alpha(x) + g_{\alpha\nu}(x) \partial_\mu \xi^\alpha(x) + \xi^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}(x) = \nabla_\mu \xi_\nu(x) + \nabla_\nu \xi_\mu(x) . 
$$
I'm going to leave this final step to you.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is the following. Start with your version and replace the partial derivatives by the covariant derivatives, i.e.,
$$
g'_{\mu\nu}(x')=g_{\mu\nu}(x)-\xi_{\mu;\nu}-\xi_{\nu; \mu} - 2 \Gamma^\kappa_{\mu \nu} \xi_\kappa,
$$
where the last term is due to the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols. Now, we have a tensorial equation. If this equation is true in one frame it should be valid in all the other frames. So just choose the Riemannian normal coordinates (NC) (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) for example) with respect to the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$, in which the connection coefficients vanish, i.e.,
$$
\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu \nu} \overset{\rm{NC}}{=} 0.
$$ 
Then, one finds the the expression you wanted to have. However, I prefer to work with the Lie derivative for this purpose.